# How to solve the PDE using direct integration or separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

[image]

I started learning PDE, I am stuck with this question.
The question is in image, How to solve it using direct integration or by separation of variables?
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8om4Q.png)

Please help.

Comment: Using an integrating factor _is_ essentially direct integration. You can't use separation of variables as the equation isn't separable.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the reply.